# Enclosing radio button with a label in Laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

To make radio buttons display correctly with the Bootstrap framework you need to enclose them in a label. Like this:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex-male" value="m">Male
    </label>
</div>
```

I have tried to accomplish this with Laravel but I can only make the label a separate element.

```
<div class="radio">
    {{ Form::label('sex-male', 'Male') }}
    {{ Form::radio('sex', 'm', true, ['id' => 'sex-male']) }}
</div>
```

Generates this HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label for="sex-male">Male</label>
    <input id="sex-male" checked="checked" name="sex" type="radio" value="m">
</div>
```

So what's the strategy here to get HTML that matches the first code block?

**Update**

The obvious way would be to cheat and do it like this:

```
<label>
    {{ Form::radio('sex', 'm', true) }}Male
</label>
```

But is there a better way?

**Conclusion**

There is no built-in way of doing this as pointed out by @lukasgeiter. So the above construction is not necessarily "wrong". For a third-party way of doing it, see the answer.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way no (without a 3rd party package at least). The `Form::label` returns straight HTML and the value parameter gets escaped... 
But I wouldn't consider it bad to have `<label>...</label>`. Laravel's helper functions aren't supposed to replace HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a useful contributed module called [Laravel Bootstrapper](http://bootstrapper.aws.af.cm/basecss) which allows you to use this format:

```
{{ Form::inline_labelled_radio('radio', 'm', 'Male') }}
```

Installation instructions can be found [here](http://bootstrapper.aws.af.cm/install)

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked if there is a better way, I find using Laravel Collective's [Custom Components](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#custom-components) the following may be done:

Register the following in App\Http\Providers\FormServiceProvider.php's boot() function

```
Form::component('bsRadio', 'components.form.radio', [
                                                      'name',
                                                      'labeltext' => null,
                                                      'value' => null,
                                                      'disabled' => null,
                                                      'inline' => null,
                                                      'attributes' => []
                                                    ]
                );
```

And in resources\views\components\form\radio.blade.php have the following:

```
@if(is_null($inline))
<div class="radio {{$disabled}}">
@endif
<?php
$a_disabled = [];
$s_disabled = '';
$s_inline = '';
if (!is_null($disabled)) {
  $a_disabled = ['disabled'=>'disabled'];
  $s_disabled = 'disabled';
}
if (!is_null($inline)) {
  $s_inline = 'class="radio-inline"';
}
?>
  <label {{$s_disabled}} {!!$s_inline!!}>{{ Form::radio($name, $value, $attributes, $a_disabled) }}{{$labeltext}}</label>
@if(is_null($inline))
</div>
@endif
```

Sample code then in a view could be like the following:

```
{{ Form::bsRadio('course', 'NLP Master', 'M', 'disabled' )}}
{{ Form::bsRadio('course', 'NLP Practitioner', 'P' )}}
{{ Form::bsRadio('course', 'Professional Blog', 'B', null, null, ['checked'] )}}
```

This will produce the following HTML

```
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label disabled ><input disabled="disabled" name="course" type="radio" value="M">NLP Master</label>
</div>
<div class="radio ">
  <label  ><input name="course" type="radio" value="P">NLP Practitioner</label>
</div>
<div class="radio ">
  <label  ><input checked="checked" name="course" type="radio" value="B">Professional Blog</label>
</div>
```

The above single component handles inline radio as well by just passing the `inline` parameter as `'inline'`.